# Wikipedia API sometimes not returning redirects

Tags: wikipedia-api

Here's a Wikipedia URL:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ps4

When I navigate to it with my browser I get redirected to this URL:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PlayStation_4

But when I try to get the redirects for `Ps4` using the Wikipedia API, it says that there are no redirects:

https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=Ps4&prop=redirects

```
{
    "batchcomplete": "",
    "query": {
        "pages": {
            "38596103": {
                "pageid": 38596103,
                "ns": 0,
                "title": "Ps4"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm guessing that I've misunderstood the API somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`&prop=redirects` [returns all redirects *to* a page](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Redirects), see:

https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=PlayStation_4&prop=redirects

To do it the other way around you should add `&redirects` to your query:

https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=Ps4&redirects

Found the documentation at [the documentation for query module:](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=query)

> Automatically resolve redirects in `query+titles`, `query+pageids`, and
>   `query+revids`, and in pages returned by `query+generator`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure why, but adding `&redirects` to the end of the URL seems to make it return the `redirects` property like I wanted:

https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=Ps4&prop=redirects&redirects

```
{
    "continue": {
        "rdcontinue": "38596106",
        "continue": "||"
    },
    "query": {
        "redirects": [
            {
                "from": "Ps4",
                "to": "PlayStation 4"
            }
        ],
        "pages": {
            "35723752": {
                "pageid": 35723752,
                "ns": 0,
                "title": "PlayStation 4",
                "redirects": [
                    {
                        "pageid": 5277874,
                        "ns": 0,
                        "title": "P s 4"
                    },
                ...
```